# Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 2 errors out website

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-power-tools

My Site was working fine and then I installed Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 2, now the site no longer works.  It seems that it must be a runtime error because there are no errors in VS 2012 IDE.  There are 40 warning pertaining to the stored procs that it created such as:

```
(EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE (name = N'vw_aspnet_WebPartState_User') AND (type = 'V'))) )
```

It states:
   Warning  1   SQL71502: Procedure: [dbo].[aspnet_AnyDataInTables] has an unresolved reference to object [dbo].[sysobjects].[type].    C:\xxxxx\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MyProjectName\dbo\Stored Procedures\aspnet_AnyDataInTables.sql   51  94  MyProjectAzure

It doesnt like the "name", "sysObjects", and "type".  in the line of code above.  This happened when I reversed-engineered-names.
But I cant seem to find out what the site is erroring to.  Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: What is the runtime error? Do the warnings go away if you close the sql file? Does the problem go away if you uninstall EF Power Tools?

Comment: I cant seem to find a way to even uninstall the EF Power Tools.  There no documentation and there doesnt seem to be any way that I see.  I would love to uninstall the EF Power Tools.  Do you know a way?

Comment: I don't have EF Power Tools installed on my box but since this is a vsix you should be able to unistall it just by going to Tools -> Extensions and Updates. Click "Unistall" button for the EF Power Tools extension.

Comment: Did it fix the runtime error you had?